# how to mongorestore mongoDB 4.2 to documentDB 4.0?

Tags: mongodb, aws, mongorestore

I need to do mongorestore from my mongodb 4.2 to DocumenDb 4.0 compatible i got the command from [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/backup_restore-dump_restore_import_export_data.html#backup_restore-dump_restore_import_export_data-mongorestore)
which is this

```
mongorestore --ssl --host="abc.aws.com:27017" --username=user --password=pass --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem dump
```

but it is showing me this error

```
[1] 1120
-bash: dGFp: command not found
[root@mongo-tf-doc01 dump]# 2021-04-06T12:10:48.434+0000        error connecting to host: could not connect to server: server selection error: server selection timeout
current topology: Type: Single
Servers:
Addr: abc.aws.com:27017:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection(abc.aws.com:27017[-121]) connection is closed
```

I am able to connect documentdb successfully so i know this is not a connection problem but error occurs when i restore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because AWS DocumentDB is only mongo 4.0 compatible and I was trying to restore from mongo 4.2, to solve this I just used AWS DMS as it was free, process is simple and there are many tutorials available from AWS and as well as other people on youtube